# TypeScript: How to make an optional second argument required based on the value of the first argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Say I have a function that takes 2 args, and depending on the value of the first arg, the second arg may or may not be required.

For Example:

```
function calculate(item: 'icon' | 'category', state: IState): void {

    if (arg1 === 'icon') {
        // code in which I don't need to access anything in state
    } 

    if (arg1 === 'category') {
        // code in which I do need to access state
    }

}
```

If I were to run this as is, I would get an error if I write

```
calculate('icon') // will cause an error
```

This will also throw an error because I am not passing a valid value for the second arg

```
calculate('icon', null) // will also cause an error
```

In order to not get any errors, I have to call it like this

```
calculate('icon', this.state) // acceptable as long as 'this.state' meets the IState definition
```

I want to be able to call the function without passing the second argument  if the first argument = 'icon'. Like this

```
calculate('icon') // should not cause an error
```

However, if I call calculate like this it should cause an error

```
calculate('category') // should cause an error
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12):

You can use multiple overloads:

```
function calculate(item: 'icon'): void
function calculate(item: 'category', state: IState): void
function calculate(item: 'icon' | 'category', state?: IState): void {

    if (item === 'icon') {
        // code in which I don't need to access anything in state
    } 

    if (item === 'category' && state) {
        // code in which I do need to access state
    }

}
calculate("icon")
calculate("category") //error
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution I ended up going with. If anyone knows of a better way please share!

```
type ConditionalOptions<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends null ? [] : [T[K]];
interface IPossibleValues {
    icon: {
        state: IState;
    };
    theme: null;
    category: {
        state: IState;
        cardItem: any;
    };
}

calculate = <T extends keyof IPossibleValues>(
    type: T,
    ...options: ConditionalOptions<IPossibleValues, T>
): string => {
    // code here
}
```

if this method is used, the value of each key in the interface IPossibleValues is what needs to be passed in to *calculate* as the second arg. Examples:

```
calculate('icon') // this will cause an error since no 'state' is passed in
calculate('icon', { state: stateVal }) // this will not generate a type error

calculate('theme') // this will not cause any type errors
calculate('theme', someValue) // this will cause an error

calculate('category', {
    state: stateVal,
    cardItem: cardVal,
}) // this will not cause an error
calculate('category', { state: stateVal }) // this will cause an error because 'cardItem' was not passed in
```

Comment: I like this solution more than Titian's answer because it is much more DRY. Only downside to this is that when you are actually calling the function TS won't immediately give you the required format for the second arg, it will just say "options is missing".