# how can I make the type of the second argument of a function dependent on the value of the first one and an entry in a map

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

based on this stackoverflow post: [TypeScript: How to make an optional second argument required based on the value of the first argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173436/typescript-how-to-make-an-optional-second-argument-required-based-on-the-value), I am trying to implement a function

```
hasRight(right: string, options: SomeOptionsBasedOnTheName) => boolean
```

where the name of the right comes from a static object, e.g.:

```
const rightList = {
   'a': {},
   'b': {
      rule: (options: {otherUserId: UserIdType}) => boolean
   },
   'c': {
      rule: (options: {accessingObjectId: ObjectIdType, accessMethod: MethodType}) => boolean
   }
}
type RightMatrix = typeof rightList;
```

where I want the second argument of `hasRight` to be the same as the first argument of the `rule` for the given right.

to access a function parameter with a given index, I have already built

```
type Arg<
    FN extends (...args: any[]) => any,
    ArgNum extends number
> = Parameters<FN>[ArgNum];

//usage:
type FirstParameter = Arg<(options: MyOptionsType, second: any) => boolean, 0>
// = MyOptionsType
```

I also am able to fetch the complete definition of the parameter using from the linked question:

```
type ConditionalOptions<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends null? [] : T[K];

export const hasRight = <R extends keyof RightMatrix>(
    right: R,
    options: ConditionalOptions<RightMatrix, R>,
) => boolean
```

however, I have problems getting the "rule" for the `Arg<FN, Index>` Type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work more or less.

```
type UserIdType = 'userIdType';
type ObjectIdType = 'objectIdType';
type MethodType = 'methodType';

const rightList = {
   'a': {},
   'b': {
      rule: (options: {otherUserId: UserIdType}) => true,
   },
   'c': {
      rule: (options: {accessingObjectId: ObjectIdType, accessMethod: MethodType}) => false,
   },
   'd': {
       rule: 'hello'
   }
}
type RightMatrix = typeof rightList;

type ConditionalOptions<T> = T extends { rule: (options: infer R) => boolean } ? R : null;

declare function hasRight<K extends keyof RightMatrix>(right: K, ...options: ConditionalOptions<RightMatrix[K]> extends never ? [undefined?] : [ConditionalOptions<RightMatrix[K]>]): boolean;

hasRight('a');
hasRight('b', { otherUserId: 'userIdType' });
hasRight('c', { accessingObjectId: 'objectIdType', accessMethod: 'methodType' });
hasRight('d');
```

You can modify `ConditionalOptions` to

```
type ConditionalOptions<T> = T extends { rule: (options: infer R, ...args: any[]) => boolean } ? R : null;
```

to accept `rule` functions with more than one parameter:

```
rule: (options: {accessingObjectId: ObjectIdType, accessMethod: MethodType}, additionalParam: string) => false,
```

**Update**: updated to allow for optional arguments if the `rule` is not of the expected type.

Comment: would it be possible to not need to pass `null` if there is no rule function or the first parameter is an empty object `{}`?

Comment: That's a good question :) I couldn't figure it out, maybe someone better versed in Typescript will chime in.

Comment: @Tobi updated the answer to allow what you asked. I based it on the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318011/optional-parameters-based-on-conditional-types